# Display all files in a folder (object) along with nested subdirectories

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Follow-up question: [Display all files in a folder (object) along with nested subdirectories part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/display-all-files-in-a-folder-object-along-with-nested-subdirectories-part-2)

**Task:** Given a main directory/folder, list all the files from it and if this directory have other nested sub-directories, list files from them also.

**Background history:** short story long - I got an internship, no past experience with asp.net-mcv-5, a nuisance of an assignment (Yet fulfilling), and now I want to optimize my code, giving the content is to be used for our intern job portal.

**Path to a functional solution:** In my quest for finding a solution have I looked at various recursive programs writing in other languages. However, they all made use of methods and after further research, I found out about @funtions in razor. It came to my conclusion, that people have different opinions on when, and if ever they should be used. That lead me to choose a different route, to finding a solution. I decided to go with Stacks inorder to store a collection of previous sub-directories, as I worked my way down each individual folder to display their content.

I would greatly appreciate feedback. And should there be any problems with my post regarding community rules, let me know.

**Ps.** My english dictionary isn't quite developed, so should you have any recommendations with how I should describe things. Please be specific, and concrete.

```
@foreach (var parentFolder in Model)
{
Stack<Folder> folderStack = new Stack<Folder>();
folderStack.Push(parentFolder);
var currentFolder = folderStack.Pop();
int dummyCounter = 1;

//Parent folder
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="btn"
           role="button"
           data-toggle="collapse"
           href="#@currentFolder.Id"
           aria-expanded="false"
           aria-controls="@currentFolder.Id">
            <span class="@GlyphionCategoryIcon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">@currentFolder.Id</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">@currentFolder.Name</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="@currentFolder.Id">

    @if (currentFolder.FoldersContained != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            //Prevents a copy of the parent folder, otherwise this display nested folders
            if (dummyCounter != 1)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <a class="btn"
                           role="button"
                           data-toggle="collapse"
                           href="#@currentFolder.Id"
                           aria-expanded="false"
                           aria-controls="@currentFolder.Id">
                            <span class="@GlyphionCategoryIcon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">@currentFolder.Id</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">@currentFolder.Name</div>
                </div>
            }
            // Create a collapse div using bootstrap 3.3.7
            <div class="collapse" id="@currentFolder.Id">
                @if (currentFolder.FoldersContained > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = currentFolder.FoldersContained; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        //Pushes all nested directories into my stack
                        //in reverse inorder to display the top directory
                        folderStack.Push(currentFolder.Folders[i - 1]);
                        dummyCounter++;
                    }
                }

                @if (currentFolder.FilesContained != 0)
                {
                    // Should they contain any files, display them
                    foreach (var file in currentFolder.Files)
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="btn"
                                   role="button"
                                   href="@webUrl@file.Url"
                                   target="_blank">
                                    <span class="@GlyphionPaperIcon"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">@file.Id</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">@file.Name</div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>

            //Ends the while loop
            if (folderStack.Count == 0)
            {
                dummyCounter = 0;
            }

            //Prepares the next nested folder object
            if (folderStack.Count != 0)
            {
                currentFolder = folderStack.Pop();
            }

        // I make use of a dummy counter inorder to break the loop
        // should there no longer be any nested directories and files
        // left to display
        } while (dummyCounter != 0);
    }

    //Finally, display all files in the parent folder, should there be any
    @if (parentFolder.FilesContained != 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in parentFolder.Files)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <a class="btn"
                       role="button"
                       href="@webUrl@parentFolder.Url"
                       target="_blank">
                        <span class="@GlyphionPaperIcon"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">@parentFolder.Id</div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">@parentFolder.Name</div>
            </div>

        }
    }
</div>
}
```

Output: (dummy data, folders expanded)
[image]

Comment: **The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code.** Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://CodeReview.meta.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Could you give an example? My code simply takes an object<Folder> and iterates through its content and display it in html. I'm using asp.net-mcv and the code is writing in razor.

Comment: For one, no need for "ASP.NET MVC Razor", that's what the tags are for. But "dynamic folder iteration HTML display" is less of a sentence, and more a bunch of words. "Displays it in HTML" is needlessly technical. Why not something like "Navigating the contents of folders on a website"? However, I don't know what your code is supposed to do, so that's something you need to describe.

Comment: This is what I call a fix! Great job ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Thanks for your kind message, greatly appriciated :)

Comment: Please do not modify the code in question after receiving answers. You can post a self-answer or a new question if you wish another review.... this needs to be rolledback.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just two comments:

- The name `dummyCounter` is really terrible, you should find something more appropriate like `currentDepth` or something but you actually don't need this at all, you can use the `folderStack` and just *ask* it whether it's not empty with `folderStack.Any()`
- You use the same *html* snippet four times (!)

  > ```
  > <div class="row">
  >     <div class="col-sm-2">
  >         <a class="btn"
  >         role="button"
  >         data-toggle="collapse"
  >         href="#@currentFolder.Id"
  >         aria-expanded="false"
  >         aria-controls="@currentFolder.Id">
  >             <span class="@GlyphionCategoryIcon"></span>
  >         </a>
  >     </div>
  >     <div class="col-sm-5">@currentFolder.Id</div>
  >     <div class="col-sm-5">@currentFolder.Name</div>
  > </div>
  > ```

  This should be a partial view that you can reuse instead of copy-pasting it everywhere. The values that are chaniging can be passed via its own new model.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I will differently look into how partial view works and it's implementation. However considering your first suggestment, I have already tired using my stack as a way to end my while loop. But it lead to missing out on the last folder, as the while loop would end after I pop the last element to prepare my the "final" loop. I also haven't firgured out a way to print my parent folder without using an if statement to skip my second folder "creating" in order to prevent duplicating my parent folder.