# Display all files in a folder (object) along with nested subdirectories part 2

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Previous post: [Display all files in a folder (object) along with nested subdirectories](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209823/display-all-files-in-a-folder-object-along-with-nested-subdirectories?noredirect=1#comment405970_209823)

**Task:** Given a main directory/folder, list all the files from it and if this directory contains nested sub-directories, list their files as well.

**Background:** It was bought to my attention that the use of dummyCounter is considered bad practices. But, I still haven't managed to find a different approach that suits my needs.
Currently, my dummyCounter is used to prevent duplicating the parentFolder, as well as allowing me to break my loop.

**My previous approach:** I have used folderStack.Any() as a condition for my while loop, but that resulted in the last nested sub-directory not getting shown. Then I tried using a "dept counter" but that proved too difficult to intercorporate while using a Stack approach to hold my data.

I would greatly appreciate community feedback. And should there be any problems with my post regarding community rules, let me know. - I tried not to repeat any of my previous issues.

**_Folder Partial View**

```
@{
string GlyphionFolderIcon = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open";
}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a class="btn"
       role="button"
       data-toggle="collapse"
       href="#@Model.Id"
       aria-expanded="false"
       aria-controls="@Model.Id">
        <span class="@GlyphionFolderIcon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">@Model.Id</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">@Model.Name</div>
```

**_File Partial View**

```
@{
string GlyphionModelIcon = "glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip";
}


<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a class="btn"
       role="button"
       href="@webUrl@Model.Url"
       target="_blank">
        <span class="@GlyphionModelIcon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">@Model.Id</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">@Model.Name</div>
</div>
```

**_Layout View**

```
@foreach (var parentFolder in Model)
{
Stack<Folder> folderStack = new Stack<Folder>();
folderStack.Push(parentFolder);
var currentFolder = folderStack.Pop();
int dummyCounter = 1;

//Parent folder
@Html.Partial("_Folder", parentFolder);

<div class="collapse" id="@currentFolder.Id">

    @if (currentFolder.FoldersContained != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            //Prevents a copy of the parent folder 
            //otherwise, this display nested folders
            if (dummyCounter != 1)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_Folder", currentFolder);
            }

            <div class="collapse" id="@currentFolder.Id">
                @if (currentFolder.FoldersContained > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = currentFolder.FoldersContained; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        //Pushes all nested directories into my stack
                        //in reverse inorder to display the top directory
                        folderStack.Push(currentFolder.Folders[i - 1]);
                        dummyCounter++;
                    }
                }

                @if (currentFolder.FilesContained != 0)
                {
                    // Should they contain any files, display them
                    foreach (var file in currentFolder.Files)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_File", file);
                    }
                }
            </div>

            //Ends the while loop
            if (folderStack.Count == 0)
            {
                dummyCounter = 0;
            }

            //Prepares the next nested folder object
            if (folderStack.Count != 0)
            {
                currentFolder = folderStack.Pop();
            }

        // I make use of a dummy counter inorder to break the loop
        // should there no longer be any nested directories and files
        // left to display
        } while (dummyCounter != 0);
    }

    <!-- //Finally, display all files in the parent folder, should there be any-->
    @if (parentFolder.FilesContained != 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in parentFolder.Files)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_File", file);
        }
    }
</div>
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this is much cooler now ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Thank you. I'm glad for the continuous support you provided so far. It has given me a good impression of code review while introducing me to some of its guidelines =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove

```
int dummyCounter = 1;
```

and change the `if`'s checking for `folderStack.Count` to an `if..else` like so

```
        //Ends the while loop
        if (folderStack.Count == 0)
        {
            break;
        } 
        else
        {
            currentFolder = folderStack.Pop();
        }
```

While writing this I thought about this

> ```
> if (dummyCounter != 1)
> {
>     @Html.Partial("_Folder", currentFolder);
> }
> ```

as well and again checked the program-flow. If we assume that the `parentFolder.FoldersContained != 0` we output the files of the `parentFolder` twice. One time inside the `do..while` loop and one time after the loop. We could remove this `if` and this

```
//Parent folder
@Html.Partial("_Folder", parentFolder);
```

like so

```
@foreach (var parentFolder in Model)
{

    Stack<Folder> folderStack = new Stack<Folder>();
    folderStack.Push(parentFolder);

    @while (folderStack.Count > 0)
    {

        var currentFolder = folderStack.Pop();
        @Html.Partial("_Folder", currentFolder);

        <div class="collapse" id="@currentFolder.Id">

            @for (int i = currentFolder.FoldersContained; i > 0; i--)
            {
                //Pushes all nested directories into my stack
                //in reverse inorder to display the top directory
                folderStack.Push(currentFolder.Folders[i - 1]);
            }

            // Should they contain any files, display them
            @foreach (var file in currentFolder.Files)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_File", file);
            }

        </div>

    }
}
```

I know that this isn't exactly the same as you had before (the most outer `<div class="collapse" id="@currentFolder.Id">` is missing) but it is much clearer and easier to read. If you need this `div`'s I would suggest to just use a separate method to process the contained folders and files of the parentFolders.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, even if they didn't nessercary solve the issue. I will how ever use them for further improvements. I think you're right about finding a different approach. And also made me aware that, just like your code doesn't work with having subdirectories showned under my parent folder. Any subdirectories greater than 1 level down wouldn't be showned as expected either unfortunately.

Wasn't aware of that mistakes giving the data I was working with didn't offer such a senario. Much appriciated.